# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, create-table

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''transactionid' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`sid`),
>     KEY `pid` (`pid`)' at line 12

```
-- Table structure for table `products`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 

`products` ( `pid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`product_img` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `currency` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'USD',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT 
 CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

 INSERT INTO `products` (`pid`, `product`, `product_img`, `price`) 
 VALUES (1, 'White T-Shirt', 'white.png', 22), (2, 'Black T-Shirt', 'black.png', 30);

  --------------------------------------------------------

  -- Table structure for table `sales`

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 

 `sales` ( `sid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `pid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `uid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `saledate` date DEFAULT NULL,
 'transactionid' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`),
  KEY `pid` (`pid`),
   KEY `uid` (`uid`)
  ) 

 ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sales`
--

 INSERT INTO `sales` (`sid`, 

`pid`, `uid`, `saledate`) VALUES
 (1, 2, 1, '0000-00-00'),
 (2, 2, 1, '0000-00-00'),
 (3, 1, 1, '0000-00-00'),
 (6, 2, 1, '2011-03-13'),
 (7, 2, 1, '2011-03-13'),
 (8, 2, 1, '2011-03-13'),
 (9, 2, 1, '2011-03-13'),
 (10, 2, 1, '2011-03-13'),
 (11, 1, 1, '2011-03-13');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the quotes around transactionid.  You need to use `` ` `` instead of `'`.

Answer (score -1):

Syntax error in this line:

```
'transactionid' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
```

it should be like the other column declarations, mean the characters around by the columnnames should not be `'` (*single quote*) and it should be `` ` `` (*backtick*) symbol

```
`transactionid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
```